# within a strip, changing second column background colour on different media

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

Using Bootstrap 3.7.

I have a full-width strip row; I have inside it a fixed-width BS container that contains a row with two equal columns. On Mobile, I want to split the two columns to show them under each other, but the catch is, I want to change the color of the right column.

Full-Width Screen (black vertical lines represent container edge)

[image: Full width]

Mobile Screen

[image: Mobile]

I want to be able, preferably without adding too many HTML contents or duplicating the entries to achieve the design below.

I was able to achieve this via duplicating the HTML content. However, I trust there are more optimal solutions to do this.

```css
#strip{
  background-color:#EFC75C;
  }

#left-col p, #right-col p {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title></title>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
  <div id="hub-container">
    <div id="strip">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div id="left-col" class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
             <p>Left col</p>
          </div>
          <div id="right-col" class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <p>Right col</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `media queries` to achieve this:

css

```
    #strip{
      background-color:#EFC75C;
      }

    #left-col p, #right-col p {
      display: block;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width:767px) {
        #right-col {
           background-color: blue;

        }
    }
```

You may need to change the pixel value in the `max-width` to the horizontal break point you want.